# Laravel query builder with array input

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I want to write an eloquent in Laravel, but I don't know how.

I have an array which contains some words:

```
$words = ["word1", "word2", "word3", ...]
```

And I have a table like this:

```
+--+--------+--------+----------+
|id| name1  |name2   |is_active |
+--+--------+--------+----------+
| 1| smthng1| anthng1| 1        |
| 2| smthng2| anthng2| 1        |
| 3| smthng3| anthng3| 0        |
| 4| smthng4| anthng4| 1        |
```

I want to write an eloquent which is equal to this query:

```
select * from `books` 
where `is_active` = 1 
and (`name1` like "%word1%" or `name2` like "%word1%") 
and (`name1` like "%word2%" or `name2` like "%word2%")
and (`name1` like "%word3%" or `name2` like "%word3%")
```

I have such an eloquent if the $words is just a single string:

```
$books = Books::where('is_active','1')->where(
                    function($query) use ($searchWords){
                        $query->where('name1', 'like', "%$searchWords%")
                            ->orWhere('name2', 'like', "%$searchWords%");
                    }
                    )
                ->get();
```

But I don's know what to do if the $words is an array of strings.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You'll just need another nested `foreach()` loop:

```
$words = ["word1", "word2", "word3"];
$books = Books::where(function ($query) use ($words) {
  foreach ($words as $word) {
    $query->orWhere('name1', 'like', "%{$word}%")
    ->orWhere('name2', 'like', "%{$word}%");
  }
})->where('is_active','1')
->get();
```

Your `WHERE` Subquery should then look something like:

```
(
 WHERE name1 LIKE '%word1%' OR name2 LIKE '%word1%'
 OR name1 LIKE '%word2%' OR name2 LIKE '%word2%'
 OR name1 LIKE '%word3%' OR name2 LIKE '%word3%'
 -- And so on for each `$word`
)
```

Edit

---

Inclusive Query would be:

```
$query = Books::where('is_active', 1');
foreach ($words as $word) {
  $books = $query->where(function ($subQuery) use ($word) {
    $subQuery->where('name1', 'LIKE', "%{$word}%")-
    ->orWhere('name2', 'LIKE', "%{$word}%");
  });
}
$books = $query->get();
```

That would produce the SQL:

```
WHERE (name1 LIKE '%word1%' OR name2 LIKE '%word1%') 
AND (name1 LIKE '%word2%' OR name2 LIKE '%word2%') 
AND (name1 LIKE '%word3%' OR name2 LIKE '%word3%')
```

Comment: This eloquent returns some extra rows that I do not want to be in $books.

Comment: The query I wrote is exclusive; if `name1` or `name2` matches _any_ of the values in `$words`, it will be returned. Your original query is inclusive, in that `name1` or `name2` must match `word1`, `word2` and `word3`. Is that correct? I can make that adjustment, but it seems odd.

Comment: Yes, correct. Thank you for the edit. But it has an error. where have I define $query? I see this error: Undefined variable '$query'

Comment: Woops; `$query = Books::where('is_active', 1');`, then `$query->where(function ...)`, then finally `$books = $query->get();`; messed up the variable naming.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is working now and returns desired data.

Comment: Excellent  Sorry for any confusion! When the system allows you, please consider pressing the Checkmark next to this answer to properly close this question. Cheers!